# Failed invoking lambda with reason Connection was closed before we received a valid response from endpoint

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, botocore

Trying to invoke a AWS Lambda from AWS EC2 instance running a python program. Both the EC2 instance and lambda are on same VPC.

```
from botocore.config import Config

adv_client_config = Config(read_timeout=60,connect_timeout=60,retries={'max_attempts': 0})

self.client = boto3.client(
            'lambda',
            region_name='us-east-1',
            config=adv_client_config
        )
response = self.client.invoke(
              FunctionName=function_name,
              InvocationType=invoke_type,
              Payload=json.dumps(request)
           )
```

InvocationType is "RequestResponse". This behavior is seen only when the 'max_attempts' is set to 0. If it is set to some value this behavior is not seen.

The call is failing within 100ms of placing call to the lambda.

Comment: what happens if you immediate make a call again while it is warm?

Comment: When the lambda is warm is works.

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda is taking a long time for a cold start. You can keep it warm by using [Provisioned Concurrency](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-provisioned-concurrency-for-lambda-functions/). You will need to figure out why your lambda is taking so much time to launch from a cold start and if there is anything you can do about it.